# Open file dialogue filter not working as intended

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog

I have created a little app that takes a file and uploads it to an SQL database. I only want the application to take .CSV files and I have applied what I believe is the necessary filter however users can still see and attempt to upload other file types which I need to restrict.

I've searched on how to filter file types and applied to the code below. I can see in the drop down box when the open file dialogue it has worked, however it's not actually filtering anything; users can still select other file types and attempt to upload them.

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
ofd.InitialDirectory = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
ofd.Filter = "CSV files (*.csv)|";
ofd.FilterIndex = 1;
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
        {
 //Do work here
        }
```

Is there anyway to either check that the user selected a cxsv and stop the process if they didn't? Or to actually do what a filter is meant to do to begin with and hide other file types? Many Thanks in advance

Comment: [FileDialog.Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter). You're missing `*.csv` after the pipe.

Comment: Ah yes so I see, thanks for pointing it out! noobie mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only set the filter label, not the file extension.

```
ofd.Filter = "CSV files (*.csv)|*.csv";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing file extension. You can refer [FileDialog.Filter Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.filedialog.filter?view=netframework-4.8) for more details.

```
ofd.Filter = "CSV files (*.csv)|*.csv";
```